# Magento 2 Get order from quote id

Tags: magento2, php, orders, quote

How would I get a order's info from a quote id?

if I have quote id of `253` and once I load that quote using..

```php
$quote = $this->quoteFactory->create()->load("253");
```

How do i get the order which belongs to this?

This would happen after the order has been placed

I've tried this but it doesn't work.

```php
$reserved_order_id = (int)$quote['reserved_order_id']); //01191
$order = $this->orderRepository->get($reserved_order_id);
```

however i get an error of `The entity that was requested doesn't exist. Verify the entity and try again` yet i know that order exists. perhaps i shouldn't use `$quote['reserved_order_id']`

## Update

```php
 $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $collection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order');
        $orderInfo = $collection->loadByIncrementId($order_id);
        $orderId = $orderInfo ->getId();
        $order = $this->orderRepository->get($orderId);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code.

In Magento 2, you can use the **`\Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface`** class to retrieve an order using a quote ID. Here's an example of how you can use this class to load an order by quote ID:

```
<?php

use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

// Quote ID
$quoteId = 1;

// Load order by quote ID
$orderRepository = $obj->create('\Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface');
$order = $orderRepository->getByQuoteId($quoteId);

// Use the order object
echo $order->getIncrementId();
```

You can also use **`\Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory`** class to load the quote and then use **`getId()`** method to get the order Id.

```
<?php
use Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory;

$quoteFactory = $this->quoteFactory->create();
$quote = $quoteFactory->load($quoteId);
$orderId = $quote->getReservedOrderId();
```

Let me know if any query.

**`THANKS.`**

Comment: hi, `$orderId` is not found -> error: `The entity that was requested doesn't exist. Verify the entity and try again.`

Comment: I used your second code snippet

Comment: Your error said you quoteId not exits. So can you try other quoteId and check.

Comment: quoteid exists, but the order id doesnt

Comment: ```$quoteFactory = $this->quoteFactory->create();
        $quote = $quoteFactory->load($quote_id);
        $orderId = $quote->getReservedOrderId();
        $order = $this->orderRepository->get($orderId);```

Comment: `$orderId` is `01199`

Comment: Yes, but without order id in DB as per magento standard it throw error which you facing.

Comment: thanks bro, see my update on my question, used that and it works nicely, just needed to use the incremented id

Comment: Great bro. Thanks for accepting answer.

Comment: no prob man, thanks for helping ;)

Comment: Welcome brother